How to change the ssh connection shell of pycharm on windows to the default bash on the server？
I installed the fish shell on my server, but I found that it seems to be detrimental to my ability to connect to the server with ssh. When I connect to the server and run it, debugging the code, everything works fine, except for the code that leads to the packages that are underlined in red, and the message that is reported by the system when I connect with ssh is something like this
enter image description here
> pwd
/home/visionx
Command finished with exit code 0
> pwd
/home/visionx
Command finished with exit code 0
Rsync command 'rsync' was not found neither in local PATH nor as full executable path
Starting introspection for Python...
> pwd
/home/visionx
Command finished with exit code 0
> echo ${SHELL}
fish: Variables cannot be bracketed. In fish, please use {$SHELL}.
echo ${SHELL}
      ^
Command finished with exit code 121
> /usr/bin/which python3
fish: Unknown command: fish:
fish: 
fish: Variables cannot be bracketed. In fish, please use {$SHELL}.
^
fish: Variables cannot be bracketed. In fish, please use {$SHELL}.
echo ${SHELL}
      ^
fish: Unknown command: ^
fish: 
      ^ -l -c '/usr/bin/which python3'
      ^
Command finished with exit code 127
> pwd
/home/visionx
Command finished with exit code 0
> sh -c "type -P python3"
fish: Unknown command: fish:
fish: 
fish: Variables cannot be bracketed. In fish, please use {$SHELL}.
^
fish: Variables cannot be bracketed. In fish, please use {$SHELL}.
echo ${SHELL}
      ^
fish: Unknown command: ^
fish: 
      ^ -l -c 'sh -c "type -P python3"'
      ^
Command finished with exit code 127
> pwd
/home/visionx
Command finished with exit code 0
> echo ${HOME}
fish: Unknown command: fish:
fish: 
fish: Variables cannot be bracketed. In fish, please use {$SHELL}.
^
fish: Variables cannot be bracketed. In fish, please use {$SHELL}.
echo ${SHELL}
      ^
fish: Unknown command: ^
fish: 
      ^ -l -c 'echo ${HOME}'
      ^
Command finished with exit code 127

Introspection completed

I would like to ask if there is any way to solve this, I don't want to change the shell on my server back to bash, can I change it from pycharm?
